# Overwriting Objects in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, object, segmentation-fault

I'm working on an assignment for school that implements a specific algorithm using a binary tree.

I've worked out the algorithm and my main() runs correctly on the first iteration, but seg faults right after that (You're supposed to be able to continuously run the program and simulate the algorithm without having to run `./main` again, hence the while loop).

I have a feeling that it has to do with my `BinaryTree *tree` being created and used on the first round, and then being used again without being freed, but my attempts to work around this have been fruitless.

Here's my main that is giving the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "BinaryTree.h"
/* Prompts user to pick an option: 
 * first fit, best fit, or quit 
*/



int main (){

    bool quit;
    int command, elements, binSize, x, totalNodes;
    cout<<"Welcome to assignment 6!"<<endl;


    BinaryTree *tree = new BinaryTree();
    //Declare new tree for use in first fit algorithm

    while (!quit)
    {
      cout<<"Choose an option for the test: 1-> First fit, 2-> Best Fit, 3-> Quit"<<endl;
      cin>>command;

        /**************
            First Fit
        **************/

        if(command==1)
        {       
            cout<<"First Fit!\n";
            cout<<"Enter number of objects: ";
            cin>>  elements;
            cout<<"Enter capacities of bins: ";
            cin>>  binSize;
            cout<<"\n";



            x=1; 
            while (elements > x)    //Get next highest power of 2 
                x=x*2;      //to fill out bottom of binary tree

            totalNodes = 2*x -1;
            for(int i=1; i<=totalNodes; i++)
            {
                //cout<<"Adding node: "<<i<<endl;
                tree->AddItem(i, -1);
            }

            bool done = false;
            //elements = x;
            int a[elements];
            for (int i=1; i<=elements; i++)
            {
                cout<<"Enter space requirement of object "<<i<<endl;
                cin>>a[i];
            }

            for (int i=1; i<=elements && !done; i++)
            {
                tree->Insert(a[i], binSize, elements);
            }

               //Loop done, seg faults happens when called again
        }
```

The BinaryTree.cpp file is a bit long so I'll link them here if it's needed: 
http://pastebin.com/EtwdBp8N

Any advice or information on bad practice is much appreciated.

Comment: Usually problems like this are use without initialization, overrunning allocated memory, or using after freeing.

Comment: compile with -g and use gdb

Comment: Specifically, set a breakpoint at what you think is the last line before the crash, and step through until you see what causes it.

Comment: The first step for things like this is to use a debugger (such as gdb) to find out exactly where the seg fault is occurring.

Comment: Q: What is your compiler?  Can you step through the debugger?

Comment: I'm using Xcode tools, compiling with g++ on Unix through terminal. 
GDB shows the error:--

 Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000020
0x0000000100001f48 in BinaryTree::Insert ()
(gdb)

Comment: Can you also give us the BinaryTree.h (pastebin is fine), then we could compile/run the code.

Comment: Can you also give us the BinaryTree.h (pastebin is fine), then we could complie/run the code.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>         int a[elements];
>         for (int i=1; i<=elements; i++)
>         {
>             cout<<"Enter space requirement of object "<<i<<endl;
>             cin>>a[i];
>         }
> ```

This bit is wrong, arrays are zero-based in C/C++, the loop should be:

> ```
>         for (int i=0; i<elements; i++)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If the debugger doesn't help, try running your program with valgrind http://valgrind.org/ or something similar.  It will identify many invalid memory accesses for you.